# How to redirect POST request using aiohttp

Tags: python, aiohttp

I'm using `python3` and `aiohttp` http server to handle requests from client.How should I redirect a POST request with body data?

I've tried

```
aiohttp.web.HTTPFound('/redirect')
```

it works with GET requests,but what if the request is POST?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect request with `body`, `headers`, etc.

```
HTTPFound(location, *, headers=None, reason=None, body=None, text=None, content_type=None)
```

See documentation: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#exceptions